# Scraped data doesn't go to the Postgres database

Tags: python, django, web-scraping

The scraper should scrape every blog post on each page
Data from the scraper should go to the Postgresql database, where the following statistics will be counted:

1. The 10 most common words along with their numbers under the address /stats
2. The 10 most common words with their numbers per author available under the address / stats /  /
3. posts authors with their name available in the address / stats /  / available under the address / authors /

so far I have focused on the first and second task but I have two problems (one results from the other and vice versa) I do not know how to make the data go to the database and thus I do not know how to do "Counter"

Here is my scraper:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from collections import Counter
import psycopg2
# from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import psycopg2


url = 'https://teonite.com/blog/page/{}/index.html'
all_links = []


headers = {
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
}
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get('https://teonite.com/blog/')
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
    all_links.append(article_links)
    num_pages = int(soup.select_one('.page-number').text.split('/')[1])


    for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
        r = s.get(url.format(page))
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        article_links = ['https://teonite.com' + item['href'][2:] for item in soup.select('.post-content a')]
        all_links.append(article_links)



    all_links = [item for i in all_links for item in i]

    d = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    contents = []
    authors = []

    for article in all_links:
        d.get(article)
        soup = bs(d.page_source, 'lxml')
        [t.extract() for t in soup(['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title'])]
        visible_text = soup.getText()
        content = soup.find('section', attrs={'class': 'post-content'})
        contents.append(content)
        author = soup.find('span', attrs={'class': 'author-content'})
        authors.append(author)
        unique_authors = list(set(authors))
        unique_contents = list(set(contents))


        try:
            print(soup.select_one('.post-title').text)
        except:
            print(article)
            print(soup.select_one('h1').text)
            break  # for debugging
    d.quit()

    # POSTGRESQL CONNECTION
    # 1. Connect to local database using psycopg2

    hostname = 'balarama.db.elephantsql.com'
    username = 'user'
    password = 'password'
    database = 'db'

    conn = psycopg2.connect(host='domain.com', user='user',
                            password='password', dbname='db')
    conn.close()

# Counter = Counter(split_it)
#
# # most_common() produces k frequently encountered
# # input values and their respective counts.
# most_occur = Counter.most_common(10)
#
# print(most_occur)

# split() returns list of all the words in the string
# split_it = contents.split()
#
# # Pass the split_it list to instance of Counter class.
# Counter = Counter(split_it)
#
# # most_common() produces k frequently encountered
# # input values and their respective counts.
# most_occur = Counter.most_common(10)
#
# print(most_occur)

# # split() returns list of all the words in the string
# split_it = contents.split()
#
# Pass the split_it list to instance of Counter class.
```

Models:

```
from django.db import models

class author(models.Model):
    author_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50, editable=False)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-author_id']
        db_table = 'author'


class stats(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stats = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-stats']
        db_table = 'stats'



class authorStats(models.Model):
    author_id = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stats = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['stats']
        db_table = 'author_stats'
```

Comment: I can't see any code that actually writes to Postgres. Why can't you use the models you defined?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find the Django Tutorial second part [found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/) very handy. This chapter handles database connections in Django applications and even specifies Postgres as an example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'm doubt that you need to use psycopg2 package to write into database if you use django. You might want to use django models instead. So this code is redundant:

```
# POSTGRESQL CONNECTION
# 1. Connect to local database using psycopg2

hostname = 'balarama.db.elephantsql.com'
username = 'user'
password = 'password'
database = 'db'

conn = psycopg2.connect(host='domain.com', user='user',
                        password='password', dbname='db')
conn.close()
```

So if you use django models in your application it makes sense to use them to store data in postgres. Django has comprehensive [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/) and it is always worth to look into it. 
For your particular example with saving `authors` it can be like this:

```
scraped_author = author(name='author name')
author.save()
```